# Windows azure sample execution problems

Tags: c#, .net, azure, mobile, service

I'm studying mobile services of windows azure, by this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/05/27/how-to-expand-linked-entities-from-mobileservices-client-and-mobileservices-service.aspx

But when i run service locally, i get following exception

```
An exception has occurred while using the formatter 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' to generate sample for media type 'application/json'. Exception message: One or more errors occurred.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can see this article

[JSON and XML Serialization in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization)

In Azure Mobile Serivce, in WebApiConfig class you need to do

```html
var config = ServiceConfig.Initialize(new ConfigBuilder(options));
config.Formatters.Clear();
config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```